# Bootstrap and JavaScript button change icon with background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im tried to change icon with background color appear on the on click event but background color not change . any solution for this?
here the my code

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#swapFire').on('click', function() {
    var $el = $(this),
      textNode = this.lastChild;
    $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-fire glyphicon-tint');

    $el.toggleClass('showFire');
 
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id="swapFire" class="btn btn-primary showFire">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Gimme Fire
</button>
```

Comment: what about setting the background you need on the already existing  CSS `showFire` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Toggle class`

```
$el.toggleClass('btn-primary btn-danger');
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#swapFire').on('click', function() {
    var $el = $(this),
      textNode = this.lastChild;
    $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-fire glyphicon-tint');
    $el.toggleClass('btn-primary btn-danger');

    $el.toggleClass('showFire');
 
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id="swapFire" class="btn btn-primary showFire">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Gimme Fire
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to also toggle btn-primary then it changes the background color

```js
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#swapFire').on('click', function () {
            var $el = $(this),
                textNode = this.lastChild;
            $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-fire glyphicon-tint');
            $el.toggleClass('btn-primary btn-success');
            $el.toggleClass('showFire');

        });
    });
```

```css
.btn {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button id="swapFire" class="btn btn-primary showFire">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Gimme Fire
</button>
```